# Handle popup window globally in automation testing using ruby watir web driver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am using watir web driver for web automation testing. I have to handle the popup window dynamically which is without title. This popup will display at any case. so i need to handle globally. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? For example, what type of popup window is it as the term has been used for quite a number of things - ie actual windows, javascript alerts, regular elements that look like poups, etc. As well, what do you mean by "handle globally" - ie what do you want to do with the popup and when do you want to do it?

Comment: HI, I have to handle "ad" type of popup (javascript alert) to click "close" button. "Handle Globally" means to catch it in environment level. ENV[popup].

Comment: Sorry, I am still having a hard time understanding what you are asking. It would help if you give HTML that shows the problem, the code you have tried and where it is you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If something like that shows up intermittently, I would (assuming you're using cucumber) make a page object for the pop up, and use it in an AfterStep hook.

Something like this

```
AfterStep do 
  pop_up = PopUpPageObject.new(self)
  pop_up.close if pop_up.present
end
```